# "I have got to sing" or "I have gotten to sing"

Tags: meaning, american-english, spoken-english, formal-language

I know that normally in American English we use "gotten" after *has/have* but in this type of construction, do Americans say "got" or "gotten"? As in

> "I have got to sing"
> or
> "I have gotten to sing"?

Comment: I'll leave it to an AmE speaker to give you an answer, but in my experience, in AmE the perfect of _get to_ (= "have the opportunity to, have the benefit of doing") is _have gotten to_ while the present of _have got to_ (= "be obliged to") is _have got to_. In BrE they are both _have got to_ and ambiguity can arise.

Comment: I have got/have to do this, I must do this= are the same in BrE and AmE. Now, the confusion comes from the fact that: the present tense of have got [which is the same as have to: have has two present tense forms in English] and the BrE present perfect: "have got" are the same thing. For example: He has got a lot of goals recently. [BrE] and He has gotten a lot of goals recently. [AmE]

Comment: @ Colin Fine and Lambie so in BrE " I have got to sing" could mean an obligation or I have been able to sing already. Am I interpreting you right?

Comment: I remember listening to an American who lived in the UK talking about the benefits she'd had from something, and saying "I've got  to ... I've got to ... " In her former life she would have said "I've gotten to ... ", but she translated that into BrE - causing confusion because that is a much less common meaning than "I have to".

Comment: @Colin Fine.I BrE. Can past tense instead of present perfect tense also express opportunity which is availed eg i got to eat burger( I ate burger)

Comment: "I went to a concert and got to meet my favourite singer" = I had (and took) the opportunity to meet them. But we wouldn't use _I have got to_ in this sense.

Comment: @kate bunting but  the first comment from Colin Fine says that "I have got to" can also be used as opportunity. Kindly refer to his comment and enlighten me.

Comment: @BilalZafar: _I have got to_ is rare in this sense, exactly because the "have to sense" is so much more common. But it can occur in a context where for some reason the "get to" meaning is expected. For example, if somebody is asked "What have you been able to do while you've been here", they might answer with "Well, I've got to ... " without being misunderstood.

Comment: @Colin Fine  cheera but i did not understand what do you mean by"have to sense" is more common? What has "have to sense" to do with opportunity which i already availed.

Comment: Sorry, I got my quotes in the wrong place. I meant _the "have to" sense_ - the meaning which is like "have to" (as opposed to the meaning like "have an opportunity")

Comment: @Colin Fine i appreciate :)

Comment: @Kate bunting @ Colin Fine @ Lambie "I got to meet my favourite singer" refers to ( I had the opportunity to meet him) but it is not compulsory that i actually met him. Am i right?

Comment: @Colin Fine as you said that i got to sing is preferable over "I have got to sing" in the sense of talking about opportunity but just in case if i use "I have got to sing" then would "have got" refers to opportunity I "have" or opportunity I "acquired"/"received"?

Comment: @Collin Fine @ Lambie as you said that i got to sing is preferable over "I have got to sing" in the sense of talking about opportunity but just in case if i use "I have got to sing" then would "have got" refers to opportunity I "have" or opportunity I "acquired"/"received"?

Comment: Yes, _I got to meet him_ implies that you _did_ meet him (that's why I added _and took_).

Comment: @Kate Bunting but according to MarclnManhattan "I got to go to the party" means "I had the opportunity to go to the party". It doesn't necessarily mean that you went. 

– MarcInManhattan.
Their is a link:
 https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/303060/i-had-got-to-eat-burger/303062?noredirect=1#comment579671_303062

Comment: Well, I would disagree. To me, _I got to [do something]_ means that you were able to do it thanks to a welcome, and perhaps unexpected, opportunity.

Comment: Cheers and I reckon same goes for "I got to know him" which indicates "I actually came to know him"

Comment: Yes, @BilalZafar, you're right that _I got to know him_ means the same as _I came to know him_; but please note that this is a different meaning of _get to_ from the one we have been discussing. This is used with verbs like _know_ and _understand_, and means something like _become accustomed to_ or _become able to_, and has no sense of an opportunity about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly as Colin Fine said, both *could* be used and they have very different meanings in American English.

**I have got to sing** means **I must sing**—I have an *obligation* or a *need* or a *drive* to sing. It is a present-tense expression of need.

**I have gotten to sing** means **I have had the opportunity to sing**. Note that this is the past tense now—we are describing an opportunity that existed at one point in the past.

Comment: Thank you Colin and randomhead.

Comment: I have got to sing, I must sing, I have to sing are all the same. have got/have meaning "have to do something" are the same in BrE and AmE.

Answer (score 1):

I got one answer from MarcinManhattan on my other thread which I am adding here. He said the same as you both said.
"I have got to go to the party" means "I have to go to the party" (present time). "I have gotten to go to the party" means "I have been able to go to the party" (present perfect).

– MarcInManhattan

Comment: Bilal, randomhead already said that. I have gotten to go the party=to have the opportunity to go to the party. Not really: been able to.

Comment: What other thread? Do you mean "question"?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A. Yes i meant question.

Comment: I did a little hunting via your profile page, EDIT  the post is here https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/303060/i-had-got-to-eat-burger it's always a good idea to post the link, it gives more context. Often users copy comments and add links, it helps avoid confusion.