# have got / have gotten

Tags: american-english, informal-language

I barely say "got" or "gotten" and thus I'm trying to add it to my vocabulary. I live in the United States and fully understand they are best used in informal context.

I see a load of resources but some seem to contradict each other.

1. https://www.grammarly.com/blog/got-gotten/ : If you live in the
   United States or Canada, you will probably choose gotten as the past
   participle of get.
2. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/get :
   North American English the past participle gotten
3. https://oneminuteenglish.org/en/have-got-vs-have-gotten/ : Have got
   and have gotten are different
4. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120721/have-vs-have-got-in-american-and-british-english :    too academic and beyond my comprehension
5. ["Gotten" versus "got"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/822/gotten-versus-got) : didn't mention "must"

At any rate, in American English in informal speech,

when I need to say "**I must leave now**", can I say "I have got to leave now" or "I have gotten to leave now"?

when I need to say "**I have bought an avacado**", can I say "I have got an avacado" or "I have gotten an avacado"?

Comment: Does [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/309358/i-have-got-to-sing-or-i-have-gotten-to-sing?rq=1) help? I'm not American, but it's my understanding that _gotten_ is only used in the sense _acquired, obtained_, so you would not say "I have gotten to leave".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression *have got to* meaning "must" always uses *got*, never *gotten*, even in AmE.

For every other use of *get*, Americans usually prefer *have gotten* to *have got*. This is not just in the principle sense of "acquire", but also for example *get to* in the sense "have the chance to".

In fact, in American English we can distinguish *I've gotten to sing in a musical* (= "I have been able to, have had the opportunity to, sing in a musical") from *I've got to sing in a musical* (="I have to sing in a musical").

In British English, both of these would be *I've got to*. Probably for that reason, *get to* is rarely used in perfect tenses in BrE.